# Cannot Show BehaviorSubject Variable in view in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, behaviorsubject

I have created this service

> Service File :

```
InfoDetails=new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

getsInfo(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.url}/Info`, data)
}
```

> In component 1:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getInfo(this.UserId);
 }
 InfoList: any;
 getInfo(userId)
  { 
  this.Service.getsInfo(json).subscribe(data => {
  if (data.response == 200) {
    this.InfoList = data.response;

    let jsons=[
      {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Test",
          "Email": "test@gmail.com",
          "Code": 4346
      },
      {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Test",
          "Email": "test1@gmail.com",
          "Code": 4346
      }
     ];

    this.Service.InfoDetails.next(jsons);
   
  }
})
  }
```

> In Component 2:

```
 let jsons=[
          {
              "Id": 4,
              "Name": "Test 1",
              "Email": "test1@gmail.com",
              "Code": 43246
          },
          {
              "Id": 67,
              "Name": "Test 3",
              "Email": "test33@gmail.com",
              "Code": 3336
          }
         ];

    this.ChatService.chatInfoDetails.next(jsons);
```

Issue is how will i loop through variable in `component 2` so that if variable value changes it should automatically reflect in the component immediately without page refresh.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated Thanks

Comment: why loop through the `jsons`? subscribe to ChatService and render when you get the next value.

Comment: @Prajwal Can you please give some example in the answer

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. If you are trying to listen to changes from service, it is not how you should be doing it. From where you are getting `jsons` value? it looks static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to render in HTML, you can just do the following.

Add a getter for the Subject. But I strongly advice, you convert the subject to an observable as shown below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  InfoDetails = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  InfoDetailsObservable$: Observable<any>;

  getsInfo(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.url}/Info`, data);
  }
  constructor() {
    this.InfoDetailsObservable$ = this.InfoDetails.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then in component 2 you can create the getter as below.

```
get infoDetails() {
    return this.ChatService.InfoDetailsObservable$;
}
```

Finally in component 2 html you need to use the async pipe and render the latest values of the behaviour subject!

```
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <pre *ngIf="!(infoDetails | async)">loading objectives...</pre>
    <span *ngFor="let test of infoDetails | async">{{ vehicle.Name }}</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer `InfoDetailsObservable$: Observable<any>;` i have not used this but the data is still be transferred from one component to other is it necessary that i have to use `InfoDetailsObservable$: Observable<any>;`, ? directly calling `return this.ChatService.InfoDetails` in the method; only issue is when i change the dropdown too fast then the data doe'nt change properly

Comment: @user3653474 Its just a matter of best practices, subject can emit events and get subscribed to, so components generally, should be able to emit events, so I have added this extra variable that components can only use and get data from, but not emit events! if you want to emit events, you need to set a method on the service like `emit(event, data) => { this.ChatService.InfoDetails.next({eventType: event, data: data})}`

Comment: @user3653474 please close this answer if your issue is resolved